# ERC4337 Account Abstraction General Concept

Tags: account-abstraction, erc-4337

I have been reading about ERC4337, and can someone verify my understanding?

1. All the RPC methods like `eth_sendUserOperation`, `eth_estimateUserOperationGas` are computed off-chain and does not interact with the blockchain directly. AA implementation need to perform the validation and processing required off-chain and push the UserOperation into the mempool.
2. The bundler implementation should watch the mempool and bundle into a normal transaction, and this is when it should interact with the blockchain.